# Enabling JavaScript based on current page

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using Laravel' Blade templating engine and write my page-specific code in a @section('script') and yield it on the main template.

The problem with this is, the code is included inline and I am unable to minify/concat this code as I do with global js code and libraries.

Is there a way to include all the JS for the application and run only the specific portion based on the page/route (a variable I can set in my views, if needed).

This would allow me to have a single JS file that is cached.

So, is setting a route variable in the global scope and then doing this, the only solution :

```
if(route == 'home') {
    // js specific to homepage
}

if(route == 'login') {
    // js specific to login
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of the 2 options,

1. Depending on the server side tech use - you should be able to create a JS endpoint that send out JS based on the condition you suggested (route being passed to the endpoint as path info. (see point 2 in this answer (based on Java as server side tech - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/283676/173234)
2. Using AJAX to download the required JS file - frameworks like AngularJS and even Dojo would do that out of the box for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Paul Irish's [DOM-Based Routing](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/). I first learned about this technique in [Sage](https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/assets/scripts/main.js), a WordPress starter theme, which uses the `body` class to route the functions. In your case, you could set the body class with a variable in your view, then use that to execute whichever function you'd like using his technique.